# Problem with read variable from AWK

Tags: shell-script, pipe

I'm trying to get memory info by this command:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cat /proc/meminfo | grep "MemFree" | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 $4 }' | read numA numB
echo $numA
```

I'm getting this

```
+ awk '{ print $2 $4 }'
+ read numA numB
+ tail -n 1
+ grep MemFree
+ cat /proc/meminfo
+ echo
```

My attempts to read these data to variable were unsuccessful. My question is how I can read this to variables? I want to read how many memory is free like: 90841312 KB

Comment: On my system, `meminfo` only has one line with `MemFree` and it only has three columns.  Are you sure you don't want your `awk` to be `'{ print $2 $3 }'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `read` and simply do the following

```
while read -r memfree
  do printf '%s\n' "$memfree"
  done < <(awk -F: '/MemFree/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try saving single values directly to each variable.  You can also remove the `cat` and the `tail` pipe by using the `-m` flag with `grep`:

```
numA=$(grep -m 1 "MemFree" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $2 }')
numB=$(grep -m 1 "MemFree" /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $3 }')

echo $numA $numB
```

Comment: You can use `/MemFree/` in awk regex pattern which does the same as `grep` is doing. No need to start another process. Also `cat` is not necessary since `awk` can read too. So you could remove `cat` and `grep` and do everything just by `awk`

Comment: Thanks @val0x00ff, I've taken your `cat` suggestion.  I feel like using `/MemFree/` regex in `awk` is well covered in your answer and at this point I'd be copying it too much.

Comment: that's fine. I learn new things by day too. It is good to see different approaches!  Thansk for sharing as well.